# Using MatToolTip with icons in Angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular, icons, tooltip

I am able to use `MatToolTip` along with a button element:

```
<button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="fn()">
                <span matTooltip="myMessage">
                  <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                </span>
              </button>
```

But on trying to use it with an icon which is within a `div` or `span` tag, it doesn't work:

```
    <div matToolTip="myMessage">
      <i style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer; " (click)="fn()" class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use the official material icon element:

`<mat-icon matTooltip="My tooltip">delete</mat-icon>`

You can of course style it however you want, enclose it in a div and give that div a class, add event listeners, etc.

Comment: Works! Aside, any idea why it worked with a button element but not with icon?

Comment: If this is your first tooltip, be sure to import the module :)           
    import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

Comment: Just to add to the comment from @chrisinmtown, the import statement should be added to the parent module, that parent module may or may not be app.module.ts

Answer (score 24):

For anyone stuck with tooltips not working, please double-check your app.module.ts file.  Make sure that your `imports: [...]` array includes `MatTooltipModule`, and that you are importing MatTooltipModule with the other imports.

If you don't include these things, tooltips simply won't work, yet there will also be no errors in the console.

I got stuck wondering why my `<mat-icon matTooltip="test">warning</mat-icon>` wasn't working, turns out this is why.

Comment: Exactly! No error in console but after importing it worked.

Comment: I imported it but nothing shows up

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking to bind variable to `matTooltip`, you need to bind it using expression  `[matTooltip]`
so it will look something like this:

```
<mat-icon class='colorInfo' [matTooltip]="tooltipVariable">info_outline</mat-icon>
```